# Issue with large no of row ehen printing in pdf with itext and java

Tags: java, pdf, java-8, itext

Hi i am generating a pdf with itext and java . Data is fetch from database based on row we got from DB , we are writing into the pdf . In my pdf when row is greater then 17 then only whole data will print into next page , If less then 17 it will print in same page . Please suggest me if no of rows is more then 17 then 17 rows will print on the same page after that new page . This is based on 17 rows .

Comment: Logic depends on you: https://medium.com/android-school/exploring-itext-to-create-pdf-in-android-5577881998c8

Comment: share your code